# String replacement and strange characters

Tags: c++, linux, string, strtok

I have an HTML data in a `char*` and I would like to get it line by line, do some replacements and then add them all up together into a single string. This is the code that I use

```
std::string to, finalData;
finalData = ""; 
char* char_array = strtok(data, "\n");
while(char_array){
    finalData += std::string(char_array);
    char_array = strtok(NULL, "\n");
}
```

The problem is the data that I get at the end of this (`finalData`) has a lot of `^M` characters and I am unable to search for it as it has a special character. Is there any way to completely eliminate the character? 
I am guessing that it has something to do with conversion from c array to c++ string and to do with `\n` as tab is represented by `^I` and cntrl is represented as `^`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are on a Windows system, or that the data originated on a Windows system. On a Windows system, newline is actually two characters: `"\r\n"`. What you are seeing as `^M` is the carriage-return character (`'\r'`) of that newline sequence.

One way to remove those extra characters, would be to use [`std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) and [`std::string::erase`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/erase) in a loop.

Another way would be to manually copy, character by character, to a new `std::string`, except if the character is `'\r'`.

Comment: I am using a linux system and the initial data is an html source of a webpage.

Comment: @PrasanthMadhavan Ah yes, many Internet protocols also uses the `"\r\n"` line-ending sequence. Anyways, I've added two ways of removing the unwanted carriage-return character.

Comment: that helped. I changed the `\n` in my code to `\r\n` and it worked.

Comment: If you want to know why `^M` is the carriage return, take a look at [an ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/index/asciifull.gif). Find carriage return and then add 64 and look at which character you find (in the linked image, just look two columns along).